# Developer Studio Project setup for Java EE doesn't allow EAR version 8 with JBoss EAP 7.2 runtime

Tags: java-ee-8

I am trying to setup a Java EE "Enterprise Application Project" in Developer Studio (version: 12.9.0.GA) with JBoss EAP 7.2 as the target runtime, but it will not allow me to select EAR version 8 (the drop-down list only goes to EAR version 7.0).

The [JBoss EAP 7.2 release note](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html-single/7.2.0_release_notes/index#supported_configs) claims "JBoss EAP 7.2 is certified for use with Red Hat Developer Studio 12" (OK so it doesn't say developer studio is certified for use with EAP 7.2)

Is there a way around this or do I have to wait for a developer studio update?

In the mean time it looks like I will have to continue using WildFly for my EE8 project runtime.